# make a jupyter notebook run even if the page is closed

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I love notebooks. I love them so much that I have many of them running at the same time, often in different browsers, sometimes on different remote clients. I miss one feature: when I close the tab corresponding to a running notebook, it warns that the corresponding run will be stopped.

My question:

> How do I make a jupyter notebook resume it's run even if the page is closed ?

such that I can:

- re-open the tab in another browser (possibly on a remote computer such as a tablet),
- restart a browser when it needs to,
- close those with long running time for later inspection.

From what I understand, the client-server architecture could make that possible, but that there may be issues with multiple concurrent runs...

PS: I created an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2446)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, this was answered in the github issue:

> `takluyver commented on 26 Apr 2017`: Anything already running in the
>   notebook will keep running, and the kernel it started for that will
>   stay running - so it won't lose your variables. However, any output
>   produced while the notebook isn't open in a browser tab is lost; there
>   isn't an easy way to change this until we have the notebook server
>   able to track the document state, which has been on the plan for ages.

Thanks!